# Display a string instead of a decimal depending on condition through binding

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, dependency-properties

I have a XAML UserControl which only has a Rectangle and a TextBlock. The Text property is set through binding with a DependencyProperty of type decimal.

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControls.TotalsDataGridCellContentControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Rectangle Fill="{Binding IsValid, Converter={StaticResource isValidConverter}, ElementName=Root}"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                   Text="{Binding Total, ElementName=Root}"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                   Margin="0 2 3 0" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

C#:

```
public decimal Total
{
    get { return (decimal)GetValue(TotalProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TotalProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty TotalProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("Total", 
                                typeof(decimal),
                                typeof(TotalsDataGridCellContentControl), 
                                new PropertyMetadata(TotalChanged));

private static void TotalChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Now I'm required to show a string like `N/A` in the TextBlock if some condition is not met. So normally if the condition is met, the value of `Total` should be displayed in the TextBlock, otherwise a string like `N/A`.

Is there an easy way to this? Like for example, add another property (string), set the value depending on the condition and bind that property to the TextBlock?

I have heard of `StringFormat` to display numbers, dates, etc. in a specific given format, but I don't think this is of any use for this case.

Comment: I imagine you can use your own IConverter to do the stringification.  Alternatively you can bind to a string-valued property in your ViewModel e.g. `uiTotal` that proxies the decimal valued `Total` property.  The latter suits my philosophy, because everything is controlled nice and explicitly in the ViewModel.

Answer (score 1):

The following should suit your needs, while (hopefully) being simple enough:

```
<Label Content="{Binding TestProp}">
   <Label.Style>
      <Style TargetType="Label">
         <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TestProp}" Value="12">
               <Setter Property="ContentStringFormat" Value="N/A" />
            </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </Label.Style>
</Label>
```

In this example the displayed string changes to "N/A" if value is 12 (though obviously you'd need to set your trigger up differently).

Comment: The DataTrigger mechanism is not available in Silverlight

Answer (score 1):

You have the following options:

If your condition can never change (so the only changing thing is the value of `Total`) you can implement `IValueConverter.Convert` (you don't need to implement `ConvertBack`) and determine the return value inside.

```
return (MeetsCondition((decimal)value)) ? value : "N/A";
```

xaml usage:

```
Text="{Binding Total, ElementName=Root, Converter={StaticResource MyValueConverter}}"
```

But if your condition changes your binding will not be evaluated as long as `Total` doesn't change. ...and will therefore display the wrong result.

Your second option:
introduce a resulting property in your code that is recalculated everytime the condition or the `Total` changes. Bind `Text` against it.

```
private static void TotalChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ((TotalsDataGridCellContentControl)d).EvaluateCondition();
}

private static void ConditionChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ((TotalsDataGridCellContentControl)d).EvaluateCondition();
}
```

Your third option (a bit too "fat" I reckon):
Define `VisualStates` "ConditionEvaluationStates" for "ConditionSatisfied" and "ConditionNotSatisfied" and show different visual elements depending on the state.